# Create new column based on codition of another column and equal distribution

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add a column to an existing dataframe.

Suppose I have this dataframe:

```
list_colors = [['black'], ["yellow"]]*4
df_colors = pd.DataFrame(List_colors, columns = ['color'])
```

which gives the following table:

| color |
| --- |
| black |
| yellow |
| black |
| yellow |
| black |
| yellow |
| black |
| yellow |

What I would like is to assign randomly but in an equal amount values to another column (`color_2`) based on the column `color`.

For example, "black" can be assigned either to "red" or "green". I want the assigning to change every time I do it, so random, but the number of "red" and "green" should be the same (in this case, 2 "red" and 2 "green"). And the same for "yellow", but with different colors (e.g, "purple" and "pink").

So something like:

| color | color_2 |
| --- | --- |
| black | green |
| yellow | purple |
| black | red |
| yellow | pink |
| black | red |
| yellow | pink |
| black | green |
| yellow | purple |

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could setup a `dict` containing a mapping from source color to a list of possible target colors, and then map each target color to a random value from the appropriate list in the `dict`:

```py
replacements = {
    'black': ['red', 'green'],
    'yellow': ['pink', 'purple'],
}
df['color_2'] = df['color'].transform(lambda x: np.random.choice(replacements[x]))
```